# Media Library empty after server migration

Tags: media, migration, library

I recently moved a client's Wordpress website to a different server. Everything is functioning great, however the media library is empty. When trying to add new files, they get stuck in crunching process and I get "an error has occurred with upload", however they do upload successfully to wp-content/uploads. They just don't display in the apparently empty media library.

So far I have:

- Disabled all plugins.
- Changed theme.
- Tried the "Add from Server" plugin.
- Updated all database URLs both manually and with plugin.
- Set file permissions on server to 755 (they already were).

I am running out of things to try. All help is appreciated.

PS. Wordpress version: 4.8.1

Comment: do you have gd php extension enabled, or imagemajik?

Comment: I don't believe so, as I haven't enabled any such features. How can I go about checking Mark?

Comment: if it is shared hosting, you should probably check you cpanel/other control panel. for a linux based VPS `php -m` from the command line might do the trick https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-list-compiled-php-modules-from-command-line/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mark! I'm using cPanel on a shared host. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Great found it. gd is enabled. as for Imagemajik, I'm not sure where I would find that.

Comment: gd should be enough.... something is brioken in your setting, try looking at the php error log for errors. The other option is that images are too big/complex and you are running out of memory while processing them

Comment: Hmm the images are quite simple. And even when I delete all my images from the server, the media library still doesn't function. I'll look into the php error log. Any other suggestions? I appreciate your help thus far.

Comment: if vanila wordpress can not upload images properly, it sounds like a server configuration issue, so last resort is contacting support

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've actually just had a breakthrough to an extent. The media library shows nothing. However when I filter by date, it shows files uploaded in July and August. But September shows as empty. Does this give any insight to the problem? Perhaps some corrupt files? Though it's strange, because when I delete the files in September, it still plays up.

Comment: if "crunching" fails it might be that the DB never gets updtaded, so older images work while newer ones don't.

Answer (score -3):

I have found that the easiest way to 'move' a blog is to clone it with WP Clone plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/ ).

You install it on the source system and do a backup. Then you install it on the target system and restore the backup. Ta-da! Both systems are exactly the same.

Although you can do it manually, it requires a lot more steps (and a hope that you don't screw up the database). I've found WP Clone to be the easiest and fastest way; there are other 'clone' plugins also available.

Since the new site is not working, you might find it easier to start over with the WP Clone plugin. It will transfer all media, adjust URLs, etc.

It is probable that the media files are there, but the URLs associated with each media file in the database are pointing to the old place.  You can fix that with some phpMyAdmin commands, but that's a lot of work - and prone to error.

That's why I let WP Clone do all the work. (and partly because I am too lazy to do all the work...)

Comment: Question is not about the backup plugins, the user needs help to resolve problems after the transfer when it is too late to think about the backup method. And your answer reads more like an advertisement than a proper answer.

Comment: And I addressed that issue (how to resolve problem In the next-to-last paragraph. I also stated that perhaps a 'do-over' might be an easier solution.